# How to avoid asp:TextBox with TextMode="Date" containing 2 dates delimited by a comma

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net 4.5 web application.

One pages (e.g. "Sample.aspx") contains one asp:TextBox, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dteEffective" Width="90" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:TextBox>
<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" class="aspBtn" onclick="validateData();" style="width: 100px;">Save</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateData() {
    var strDate = document.getElementById('<%= dteEffective.ClientID %>').value; // this contains the correct vcalue "2023-06-12"
    callbackValidate_Callback(null, null);  // This will call ValidateCallback() in code-behind
}
...
</script>
```

I initialized it to today in Sample.aspx.cs,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ...
        dteEffective.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
```

It displayed 06/13/2023 correctly.
When I changed it to 06/12/2023 and clicked "Save", it called a callback I defined, namely, ValidateCallback().

[image]

When I examined the text value of dteEffective in the callback function, I expected it to be "2023-06-12" but it was "2023-06-12,2023-06-13" (i.e. the last picked date + "," + the initial date).

This is the callback function in Sample.aspx.cs,

```
protected void ValidateCallback(CallbackControl sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string validationType = sender.ArgumentParameter.ToString();
    message = null;
    string strDateEffective = dteEffective.Text;    // not "2023-06-12" but "2023-06-12,2023-06-13"

    try
    {
        Validator validator = new Validator();
        DateTime dteEff;
        DateTime.TryParse(dteEffective.Text, out dteEff);   // This causes validation error
        validator.CheckDateErrors(String.Empty, "Effective Date", dteEffective, DateTime.Now, Validator.DateOptions.Required | Validator.DateOptions.NotBefore1935);
        validator.ValidateFields();
        message = validator.JavascriptErrorString(hdSoftEdits); // hdSoftEdits is a hidden field in case an error occurs.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Common.LogError(ex);
        message = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
    }
    sender.RenderedOutput = message;
}
```

Why does this happen?
How can I avoid it?

Comment: Can you please add code where you call `ValidateCallback()` function?

Comment: Just added Save event and its function.

Comment: Please add full code of `ValidateCallback` function

Comment: updated again, but our custom functions were used in ValidateCallback.